# Access to value of comboBox on selectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `comboBox` with `SelectedItemChanged` event. So I want to extract value of selected item like:

```
private void cboCustomerType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new SQLConnMgr();

    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    var comboSelectedValue = cmb.SelectedItem;
}
```

Problem is value I want is on  `cmb.SelectedItem.Row.ItemArray[1]`
[image]

But I can't access to `cmb.SelectedItem.Row`. Why I can't do as simple as: `cmb.SelectedItem.Row.ItemArray[1]`? Regards

Comment: What is the type of the object that you've set as the DataSource for your combobox?

Comment: it's a datatable @HandbagCrab

Comment: `SelectedItem` is Object because almost anything can be stuffed into a CBO.  Intellisense knows the real type and shows you but you have to cast it to access the props.  If it is bound, SelectedValueChanged would be a better event to use and the ValueMember obviates the need to unwrap everything

Answer (score 1):

Your selected item type is DataRowView so you need to cast SelectedItem to that:

```
private void cboCustomerType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // A combobox with nothing selected will have a SelectedIndex of -1
    if (cboCustomerType.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        // Cast SelectedItem to DataRowView
        DataRowView item = cboCustomerType.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        if (item != null)
        {
            // Access the data in column 1 of the selected row
            string value = item[1].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are binding combobox with `DataSet`. So you can do this:

```
DataRow dataRow = dataSet.Select(string.Format("FieldName = '{0}'",     ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()))[0];

if (ComboxBox.SelectedValue != null)
{

// can use fields like 

String text = dataRow[“fieldName”].ToString();
}

else
{ //something wrong
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
```

write

```
ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
```

This way it worked for me.